Incomplete params inside cy.wait()
This is the bug I'm facing I do not understand why the params are not fully gotten with the cypress wait function
thenfunction(){}
AssertionError
expected '19/0' to equal '19/01/2028'
/* eslint-disable mocha/no-setup-in-describe,no-undef,mocha/no-skipped-tests */
// noinspection ES6ConvertRequireIntoImport
require('chai/register-expect');
const {basicResponseObj, bodyObjSearch2} = require("./common");


describe('Stubbed suite', function() {
    // Step 1: setup the application state
    beforeEach(function () {

        cy.clearCookies();
        cy.clearLocalStorage();
  
        cy.intercept('GET', '*/entries?usage=basic*', {body: basicResponseObj});
        cy.intercept('GET', '*/entries?usage=search*', {body: bodyObjSearch2}).as("searchResults");;
        cy.visit('search-test');
    });

    describe('Search by date range', function () {

        it("Fill filter and check query param is filled", () => {
            cy.get('#date-from').type("19/01/2028")
            cy.get('#date-to').type("19/01/2028")
            cy.get('#search-btn').click();
            cy.wait("@searchResults").then((req) => {
                expect(req.request.query.dateFrom).to.eq("19/01/2028");
              });
          });
   
          });
        })

 


It's probably not the intercept that fails, more likely the type needs a delay or some other adjustment.
To check, add an assertion after type()
cy.get('#date-from').type('19/01/2028')
cy.get('#date-from').invoke('val').should('eq', '19/01/2028')

then add in delay to make the .type() stable
cy.get('#date-from').type('19/01/2028', {delay, 100})


Thanks for your response But invoke is giving
assertexpected '' to equal 19/01/2028

.invoke('val') is the correct command to check the typed-in value, for <input> or <textarea> elements.

How I managed to solve this is with adding the api interception to a beforeEach hook
to make sure it is used by every test case and changing the first hook beforeeach to a before hook.
describe('Stubbed suite', function() {
    // Step 1: setup the application state
    before(function () {

        cy.clearCookies();
        cy.clearLocalStorage();
  
        cy.intercept('GET', '*/entries?usage=basic*', {body: basicResponseObj});
        cy.intercept('GET', '*/entries?usage=search*', {body: bodyObjSearch2}).as("searchResults");;
        cy.visit('search-test');
    });

    describe('Search by date range', function () {
        beforeEach(function() {
            cy.intercept('GET', '*/entries?usage=search*', { body: bodyObjSearch2 }).as("searchResults");
          });
        it('Type date from and date to', () => {
            cy.get('#date-from').type("19/01/2028");
            cy.get('#date-to').type("20/01/2028");
            
        })

        it("Check query param is filled", () => {
            cy.get('#search-btn').click();
            cy.wait("@searchResults").then((req) => {
                console.log(req.request.query)
                expect(req.request.query.dateFrom).to.eq("19/01/2028");
                expect(req.request.query.dateTo).to.eq("20/01/2028");
              });
          });
   
          });
        })

